# Laravel table: there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have made all integers unsigned but I still get the error. What do I need to change?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFacebook extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('facebook', function($table)
        {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('username', 255);
        $table->bigInteger('uid', 20)->unsigned();
        $table->string('access_token', 255);
        $table->string('access_token_secret', 255);
        $table->string('photoURL', 255);
        $table->string('profileURL', 255);
        $table->string('firstName', 255);
        $table->string('lastName', 255);
        $table->string('gender', 255);
        $table->string('age', 20);
        $table->integer('birthDay')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('birthMonth')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('birthYear')->unsigned();
        $table->string('email', 255);
        $table->string('phone', 30);
        $table->string('address', 255);
        $table->string('country', 100);
        $table->string('region', 100);
        $table->string('city', 100);
        $table->string('zip', 20);
        });
        }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('facebook');
    }

}
```

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be de     fined as a key

Thank you.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use

```
$table->bigInteger('uid')->unsigned();
```

instead of

```
$table->bigInteger('uid', 20)->unsigned();
```

**Infos:**

in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint` you can see the bigInteger function:

```
public function bigInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
```

So 20 (not being 0) evals to `true`.

While `string` method has as second parameter `length`:

```
public function string($column, $length = null)
```

Therefore if you use any integer blueprint (`bigInteger`, `mediumInteger`, `tinyInteger`, `smallInteger`, etc...) with any second parameter (other than 0) you are telling Laravel to make an integer with an `auto_increment` property, this will return:

`Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key")`

Comment: An explanation would be nice (not for me, I know why, but for other people and possibly also the OP)

Comment: Yes, you right. in file /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint we can find definition:
`public function bigInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false) ` . So 20 == true :)

Answer (score 6):

Specify the size for bigInteger column by following way

```
$table->bigInteger('uid')->length(20)->unsigned();
```

Comment: This helped me, I was using ('uid', 20) instead of length method.